# How to use two hash on samepage?

Tags: jquery, html, hash

Hello I am trying to use this script called " Filterable portfolio " but it uses hash and alredy my site use one, and when I try to load a hash its makes conflict, Is there any way to use two hash'es?

My page example is

> mysite.com#portfolio.php

And the filterable portfolio uses #example

and if I put

> mysite.com#example

Don't work it need to be something like this.

> mysite.com#portfolio.php#example

Here is the JS of Filterable portfolio

> ```
> /*
> * Copyright (C) 2009 Joel Sutherland.
> * Liscenced under the MIT liscense
> */
>
> (function($) {
>   $.fn.filterable = function(settings) {
>       settings = $.extend({
>           useHash: true,
>           animationSpeed: 1000,
>           show: { width: 'show', opacity: 'show' },
>           hide: { width: 'hide', opacity: 'hide' },
>           useTags: true,
>           tagSelector: '#portfolio-filter a',
>           selectedTagClass: 'current',
>           allTag: 'all'
>       }, settings);
>
>       return $(this).each(function(){
>
>           /* FILTER: select a tag and filter */
>           $(this).bind("filter", function( e, tagToShow ){
>               if(settings.useTags){
>                   $(settings.tagSelector).removeClass(settings.selectedTagClass);
>                   $(settings.tagSelector + '[href=' + tagToShow + ']').addClass(settings.selectedTagClass);
>               }
>               $(this).trigger("filterportfolio", [ tagToShow.substr(1) ]);
>           });
>
>           /* FILTERPORTFOLIO: pass in a class to show, all others will be hidden */
>           $(this).bind("filterportfolio", function( e, classToShow ){
>               if(classToShow == settings.allTag){
>                   $(this).trigger("show");
>               }else{
>                   $(this).trigger("show", [ '.' + classToShow ] );
>                   $(this).trigger("hide", [ ':not(.' + classToShow + ')' ] );
>               }
>               if(settings.useHash){
>                   location.hash = '#{key}=#{value}' + classToShow;
>               }
>           });
>
>           /* SHOW: show a single class*/
>           $(this).bind("show", function( e, selectorToShow ){
>               $(this).children(selectorToShow).animate(settings.show, settings.animationSpeed);
>           });
>
>           /* SHOW: hide a single class*/
>           $(this).bind("hide", function( e, selectorToHide ){
>               $(this).children(selectorToHide).animate(settings.hide, settings.animationSpeed);   
>           });
>
>           /* ============ Check URL Hash ====================*/
>           if(settings.useHash){
>               if(location.hash != '')
>                   $(this).trigger("filter", [ location.hash ]);
>               else
>                   $(this).trigger("filter", [ '##' + settings.allTag ]);
>           }
>
>           /* ============ Setup Tags ====================*/
>           if(settings.useTags){
>               $(settings.tagSelector).click(function(){
>                   $('#portfolio-list').trigger("filter", [ $(this).attr('href') ]);
>
>                   $(settings.tagSelector).removeClass('current');
>                   $(this).addClass('current');
>               });
>           }
>       });
>   }
> })(jQuery);
>
>
> $(document).ready(function(){
>
>   $('#portfolio-list').filterable();
>
> });
> ```

And here is the Navigation for page.

> ```
> <div class="wrapper" id="contentWrapper"> <div class="boundingBox" id="content">      <ul id="portfolio-filter">
>           <li><a href="#0" title="" rel="0">#</a></li>
>           <li><a href="#portfolio.php#a" title="" rel="a">A</a></li>
>           <li><a href="#portfolio.php#b" title="" rel="b">B</a></li>
>           <li><a href="#portfolio.php#c" title="" rel="c">C</a></li>
>       </ul></p>
>
>
> <ul id="portfolio-list">  <div id="a"> content A</div>  <div id="b"> content B</div> <div id="c"> content C</div>  </ul>
> ```

Comment: Well whichever runs first you could edit as it will be one hash with a value of `#portfolio.php#a` - so you could split by `#` then use the one you need, and rewrite the hash to the value that the next script wants. Seems a bit messy though, would rather use different plugin/change site functionality

Comment: @SmokeyPHP: Nope, the hash is not a valid char for a fragment identifier: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.5

Comment: Have a look here, it's related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/566276/1686330